# How do I print out a pipeline's or a stage's parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

Let's say I have the following stage and pipeline:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  lockBehavior: sequential
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!
```

```
lockBehavior: runLatest
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    steps:
    - script: Hey!
```

How would I print out the lockBehavior parameter out in Azure Devops when running the pipeline? I have tried printing out all variables using this code:

```
jobs:
- job: testing
  steps: 
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'env | sort'
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the parameters "lockBehavior" from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update) . But I haven't found out a method to show the value in the pipeline log. However, there is a note "If you do not specify a lockBehavior, it is assumed to be runLatest." In my view,it's not hard to know the value if you set up it by yourself.

As my experience, you can print some "Use predefined variables" or "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script" by following the [offical doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

So i guess that perhaps this parameter will be added in the future in the "Use predefined variables".